# Add an unknown number of strings to DynamoDB

Tags: php, arrays, string, numbers, amazon-dynamodb

In my PHP script, I get a POST reaction from an HTML form. One of the texts, is a list of things, separated by a comma (for example: `"apple, banana, orange"`).

I want to upload this text, among with other texts which got POSTed to a table on Amazon DynamoDB, but I don't want to upload it as a string, but as a string set (for example: `["apple", "banana", "orange"]`).

Now, I know how to split the string:

```
$list = "apple, banana, orange";
$fruits = explode(", ", $list);
echo $fruits[0]; // apple
echo $fruits[1]; // banana
echo $fruits[2]; // orange
```

And, I also know how to upload a string array to DynamoDB:

```
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk([
    'region'   => 'us-west-2',
    'version'  => 'latest'
]);

$dynamodb = $sdk->createDynamoDb();

$response = $dynamodb->putItem([
    'TableName' => 'ProductCatalog',
    'Item' => [
        'Id'       => ['N'      => '104'      ], // Primary Key
        'Title'    => ['S'      => 'Book 104 Title' ],
        'ISBN'     => ['S'      => '111-1111111111' ],
        'Price'    => ['N'      => '25' ],
        'Authors'  => ['SS'  => [$authorA, $authorB] ]
                ]
]);
```

But, how to upload the strings, if I don't know the exact number?

If I knew the number of items then it would be like:

```
'Fruits' => ['SS' => [$fruits[0], $fruits[1], $fruits[2]]
```

But the problem is that I don't know.
How can I upload the string array to DynamoDB although I don't know the exact number of strings in the array?

Comment: Are you sure this won't work: `'Fruits' => ['SS' => $fruits]`?

Comment: @xtx I don't know. I saw this code on AWS website. I'll check it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `$fruits` as value as below :

```
 $response = $dynamodb->putItem([
 ....
 ....
 'Fruits' => ['SS' => $fruits]
```

It is already an array, So it will be automatically stored as document / json structure.